# Managing Multiple Git Repo's in Visual Studio NOT in TFS

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, version-control

I'm new to Git moving from TFVC (TFS 2013) backed by Atlassian Stash (Git server) to integrate better with Atlassian's stack (Bamboo, etc.).

I'm following the pattern of NOT putting all projects in one monolithic repository.  However, Visual Studio does not recognize the other repositories it seems and I can only commit to my main project/solution in the repository where the solution exists.  Other class libraries from other repositories on disk cannot be managed within VS such as commit, push, pull, etc.

Is there any way to better handle this in Visual Studio or must I manage all version control now external to VS?

Comment: Do you have several *independent* repositories?  Or do you have a repository with several submodules?

Comment: @EdwardThomson I am not using submodules - all are cloned independent from the server and a solution in VS created by adding existing projects.

Comment: And the solution thus references code from multiple independent git repositories?

Comment: @jessehouwing yes - that is correct.